# Add method to go quickly from one question to another without having to go BACK to index

Tags: feature-request

I have something that has bothered me in SE and I think this needs a feature to be implemented.

I want to go from question to question quickly without having to go to BACK to an index page all the time and staying within one page. Switching back and forth between pages is what I am trying to avoid and would save a lot of time.

Maybe what I am suggesting is an abbreviated index while displaying the question on either the Right or Left column?

I'm NOT suggesting a NEXT/PREV button either since that was previously rejected.

Thanks for your consideration, perspectives, and possible alternative implementations of what I am trying to get implemented.

Comment: For what purpose/use case? Don't tabs essentially facilitate this?

Comment: Not really.  I want to read through a lot of questions, I have to follow the loop: read question;BACK to return to index; until I am finished.  Why can't I get at another question while reading the question, thus saving me a lot of time and effort, getting the previous page, waiting for it to redisplay, and selecting the next question.  Seem like you could cut down some traffic as well.

Comment: Does the list of related questions (to the right, under "Related") somehow not accomplish this?

Comment: You simply can't _read_ a question and _read_ a summary simultaneously - you have to do one first then the other - I don't see how reading summaries, opening tabs, then conquering those individually, isn't suitable.

Comment: On the right, I would like to have basically the abbreviated questions list that I saw.

Comment: The index on the right would be a title only index, not a summary.

Comment: The NEXT/PREV is not necessarily what I am requesting here.  Thus it is not a duplicate of what I am envisioning.

Comment: For the record, I disagree that this is a duplicate.  I am NOT suggesting a NEXT/PREV button as that was previously rejected.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think this is necessary.

Your browser probably supports a tabbed user interface (if it doesn't, you should try it, it's surprisingly useful). You can leave the index page open in one tab and open questions in their own tabs (usually with the middle mouse button).

From there:

- To get back to the index: 1 click,
- To get to an already open question: 1 click,
- To open a new question from the index: 1 click.

Which is quite efficient IMHO.

Comment: You don't even need to use such an archaic and counter-productive device as a mouse to drag back and forth a cursor over the screen and clicking - it's even quicker with the keyboard to flick between tabs.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment, true, I do not usually use these shortcuts myself, but that's a hardware limitation. (French laptop keyboards make `Ctrl+<number>` shortcuts either harder to type or unreliable, sometimes both :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Control-Tab?

Comment: @Keith, *n* times? I'd rather click ;)